# get rid of log4j 1.2.12 from cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, log4j

I have a requirement to get rid of log4j v1.2.12 due to the vulnerabilities. My app is spring boot 2, i have in my gradle:

```
configurations.all {
exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
```

}
I wipe out my cache, run a build on my project and this lib shows up again:

```
.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/log4j/log4j/1.2.12
```

when i run

```
gradle -q dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency log4j
```

It doesn't show me use of that version of log4j. Same with the whole dependency tree on a project, no where this version of log4j shows up.
What is going on here? How do i get rid of it?

What's the way to see how gradle builds my local cache?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle cache is not reflective your project alone. It may be from any other project that you build or some other transitive dependency. For your project - you can additionally generate `htmlDependencyReport` and check from

```
plugins {
    id 'project-report'
}
```

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/project_report_plugin.html

Comment: thank you. I deleted cache and build only one project. there should be no other projects contributing to the cache creation.

Comment: i've tried this:
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    }
} dependency report shows to me log4j:log4j:1.2.17 but cache has only .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/log4j/log4j/1.2.12 directory. 
I m missing something here. Help.

Comment: if you asking about 1.2.17 -> 1.2.12     there will be reason for version resolution in the dependency report ; some dependency is forcing downgrade

Comment: PrasadU, no where in report log4j version 1.2.12 is indicated. However, it loaded into my local cache.